# Intersection of two sets from three given sets?

Tags: java, set

I have to write an algorithm that finds the intersection of two sets from three given sets. For example, if the element exists in two of the three sets it is good, but if the element is in all three sets then it should not be added

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: Hi Mark! Welcome to StackOverflow, this question as it is, is too broad, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get an idea of how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a hashmap
2. Iterate through each set, add element as key with value of 1 if key not in hashmap already, if key in hashmap increment value by one.
3. Iterate through hashmap and create your result set with keys that have value of two.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to collect all the sets together, count the frequency of each element, and keep only the ones that appears twice

Using Streams

- a stream with the 3 sets
- a stream of all elements of the 3 sets concatenated
- build a map
- iterate over pairs
- keep ones with value == 2
- keep only key
- collect to a set

```
static <T> Set<T> intersectionTwoButNotThree(Set<T> s1, Set<T> s2, Set<T> s3) {
    return Stream.of(s1, s2, s3)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == 2)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

With loops

```
static <T> Set<T> intersectionTwoButNotThree(Set<T> s1, Set<T> s2, Set<T> s3) {
    Map<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (T elt : s1) 
        map.merge(elt, 1, Integer::sum); // sum previous value and 1
    for (T elt : s2) 
        map.merge(elt, 1, Integer::sum); // sum previous value and 1
    for (T elt : s3) 
        map.merge(elt, 1, Integer::sum); // sum previous value and 1

    Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (Map.Entry<T, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) 
        if (e.getValue() == 2) 
            set.add(e.getKey());

    return set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my attempt

```
public class Test {

    List<Set> sets = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> one = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> two = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> thr = new HashSet<>();

    enum EStatus{
        IT_IS_GOOD,
        SHOULD_NOT_BE_ADDED,
        EPIC_FAIL
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test mainT = new Test();
        mainT.prepareData();
        System.out.println(mainT.doStuff("three"));
    }


    public EStatus doStuff(String element){
        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
            Set<String> intersectionOfTwo = new HashSet<>(sets.get(i-1));
            intersectionOfTwo.retainAll(sets.get(i % 3));
            if(intersectionOfTwo.contains(element)){
                Set<String> intersectionOfThree  = new HashSet<>(intersectionOfTwo);
                intersectionOfThree.retainAll(sets.get((i + 1) % sets.size()));
                if(intersectionOfThree.contains(element)){
                    return EStatus.SHOULD_NOT_BE_ADDED;
                }else{
                    return EStatus.IT_IS_GOOD;
                }
            }
        }
        return EStatus.EPIC_FAIL;
    }

    public void prepareData(){
        one.add("one");
        one.add("two");
        one.add("three");
        two.add("two");
        two.add("three");
        thr.add("three");
        thr.add("four");
        sets.add(one);
        sets.add(two);
        sets.add(thr);
    }
}
```